# How to manipulate equation in Matlab or python?

Tags: python, matlab, sympy, symbolic-math

I have a complicated equation which is function of several variables and I want to manipulate like this example:

```
y = (x + a) / z 

x = y*z - a
```

Is it possible to do this kind of manipulation matlab or python?

If there is possibility then please point out method or function to do this operation.

I tried following code in Sympy Shell:

```
x,y,z,a = symbols ('x y z a')
solve ( y = (x-a)/z, x)
```

I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Comment: Are you asking how to symbolically solve for `x`?

Comment: Are you looking to solve an equation for a variable? Or do algebraic manipulation?

Comment: algebraic manipulation

Comment: You can use Microsoft Mathematics. It is the easiest maths problem solving tool.

Comment: Firstly shouldn't it be `(x + a)`? Secondly, sympy assumes your equation is set to equal 0 (first line of the docs: http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/solvers/solvers.html) which in your case means just changing the `=` to `-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Matlab you'd need the symbolic math toolbox (which I don't have so I can't test) and then you should be able to do use the [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html?refresh=true#btrwa0u-2) function:

```
syms y x a z
solve(y == (x+a)/z, x)
```

I have NO experince with `sympy` but pretty sure [based on the docs](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/solvers/solvers.html) this is how you do it:

```
from sympy import solve, Poly, Eq, Function, exp
from sympy.abc import x, y, z, a
solve(y - (x+a)/z, x)
```

Comment: Can this method use for algebraic manipulation. I tried to do it in python and it is not possible with sympy.

Comment: Did you read the examples in the Docs I linked to? Is that not what you're after? ...Also I'm quite sure this is possible in Python, if you have tried it then you should just add your code to your question and I'm sure someone will be able to correct it for you

Comment: @User1551892 I added some SymPy code (not tested, purely based on the doc examples) - see if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

SymPy is a Python library, so your SymPy code needs to be valid Python. In Python, `=` is the assignment operator, which is why `solve ( y = (x-a)/z, x)` gives a SyntaxError. See http://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#equals-signs.

To create an equality in SymPy use `Eq`, like `solve(Eq(y, (x - a)/z, x)`, or use the fact that expressions in SymPy are assumed to be equal to zero, like `solve(y - (x - a)/z, x)`.